# Java read files in folder and sub-folders

Tags: java, file-io

I'm making a program that changes gray-scale images to black and white images, the program has to read all .png files from folder and sub-folders and after editing them save to a new dir. Every thing worked as intended but I made some changes and the program now only reads files from the first folder or sub-folder that has images.

```
public class FindFiles {
public void find(String dir, String finDir){ 
    try {
        File folder = new File(dir);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        ChangeColor change = new ChangeColor();

        for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                change.ChangeC(dir, finDir, listOfFiles[i].getName());
            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                File f = new File(finDir+"/"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                    new File(finDir+"/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()).mkdirs();
                }
                find(dir+"/"+listOfFiles[i].getName(),finDir+"/"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }   
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FindFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

I would appreciate your help in finding out the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider cleaning up your code first, then looking for the error:

```
public class FindFiles {
    public void find(File src, File target) {
        assert(src.isDirectory() && target.isDirectory());
        try {
            File[] fileList = src.listFiles();

            ChangeColor change = new ChangeColor();

            for (File file : fileList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    change.ChangeC(file, target);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    // create the File object for the directory name
                    File newDir = new File(target, file.getName());
                    newDir.mkdir();
                    find(file, newDir);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FindFiles.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You have a lot of unnecessary generation of `File`s and mixing Strings and `File`s when a `File` will do.

You'll need to change the signature of `ChangeColor.changeC()` to accept the `File` object that needs to be converted from the source directory and a `File` object for where it should be written to in the form of the target. The method should make sure the second parameter is a directory as I did here -- never trust a caller!

I haven't tested this code and there's a few other things I'd do differently (like exception handling), but I didn't want the structure to be too different so you could visualize the changes more easily.

What I did here is a form of **Defensive Coding**. Spend time with Occam's Razor to get the code down to the bare minimum *up front*. Choose variable names that will make sense *when reading the method*, not names that look good at the top (and don't be afraid to keep changing them until it reads easily). Bugs that exist will be a lot clearer to find and you will save a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Thx for the answer and the advice i know that the code was atrocious. Btw I found the bug, I forgot to check  if a file was a png before changing the color, so a hidden file was read because of this.

Comment: Nobody starts writing perfect code, no worries! Have fun!